# Check file content looking for corruption, file size indicates size "zero"

Tags: find, xargs

I have a very strange situation where I have a file system that contains a number of files that are of varying size but appear to have been corrupted and show no contents when cat-ing the file.

I have no idea how many of these files there are and they look like all the other files around them. So far the best method I've found to discover them is to run `find . -type f | xargs wc -l` and look for the files that return 0.

However, some of these files are 10s of GB and even when they're empty take over a minute to check one file. I have to check approximately 50 million files, so that's pretty much a non-starter.

My biggest question is if there's a lower level way to check the contents of these files that will be much faster than running a simple find.

Comment: No output from `cat` does not mean that the file is empty. There are reliable methods such as `find` or `stat` or shell features to find empty files.

Comment: I tried that, these files don't show up using the empty flag because they still have some sort of contents. It's just not the content that is expected. When trying to open these files with less, it thinks they are a binary file and shows garbled content, but these are (supposed to be) regular text files.

Comment: @countermode - could you please elaborate further on these features you mention? I know these files aren't empty, but they no longer contain their original data in a useful format.

Answer (score 4):

> and show no contents when cat-ing the file.

No output of `cat` for a file does not imply that the file is empty as the following experiment shows:

```
$ truncate -s 1M foo    
$ ll foo
-rw-r----- 1 user users 1048576 Nov 15 19:28 foo
$ file foo
foo: data
$ cat foo
$
```

`cat` does output 1MiB worth of NUL characters, but those characters happen to be invisible in a terminal.

Your question about empty files is somewhat ambiguous. Does `foo` above qualify? If "empty" means length zero, then `find` could aid you:

```
find dir -type f -empty
```

lists all zero length files under `dir`. If your `find` doesn't support `-empty`, you can use `-size 0` instead.

In shell scripts you may use the `-s file` expression which is true if `file` exists and is non-empty. In order to check whether a file is empty (given that it exists) use something like

```
if [ \! -s file ] ; then ... ; fi
```

Alternatively, you may use `stat(1)`. Here with the GNU variant:

```
$ stat --format=%s foo
1048576
```

which you may use further in comparisons.

Answer (score 4):

From your clues:

- they are or non-0 size, as reported by `ls -l`
- that `cat`ing them appears to show nothing
- `wc -l` returns 0.

We can tell:

- they contain no newline character (`wc -l` counts the newline characters)
- if they contain any character, they are invisible in a terminal

While there are a great number of characters that are invisible in a terminal like most control characters, and some extended unicode ones, for many different *corrupt* files to show that behaviour makes me think that's likely to be the NUL character.

A corrupt file can be seen as all-zeros if all references to data blocks have been removed to it, with the *size* attribute in the inode left intact. That's fully sparse files.

Unless the block count field in the inode is also corrupted, you may be able to detect those with (assuming GNU `find` and `awk`):

```
find . -size +0 -printf '%b%p\0' | awk -v RS='\0' '
  /^0/{print substr($0, 2)}'
```

That is, find files whose size is non-zero but disk usage is null.

Answer (score 0):

> My biggest question is if there's a lower level way to check the contents of these files that will be much faster than running a simple find.

Try `du`:

```
$ truncate -s 4G my4g
$ ls -l my4g
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tange tange 4294967296 Mar  4 15:34 my4g
$ cat my4g
$ du my4g
0       my4g
```